# HTML Select dropdown with dynamic list in Django ModelForm

Tags: html, django, django-models, modelform

**In the view** : I need to display a dropdown list of years starting from a fixed value (say 2005) to the current year. Now, this list, though dynamic, does not come from the database. Also, I want the list to expand as time goes by.

**In the model** : I want this field to be like an IntegerField(?) which saves values only from 2005 to, say, 3000, and throws a validation error otherwise.

What I could do - Make the dropdown as a ChoiceField in the View, and set up a validator for the model.

What I want - I want to use ModelForm in Django since this field, along with others in the form maps to the fields of my model. It means that I wont be defining fields in my Form, but only in the model. The question is, therefore, what should my approach be?

This I have tried so far-

```
class Member(models.Model):
    d = int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y"))
    ch = [(X,X) for X in range(2005,d)]
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    membership_type = models.IntegerField(validators=[validate_membership_type])
    batch = models.IntegerField(choices= ch)
```

This generates the form with desired select field but the values do not change. I replaced 'Years' by 'Minutes' to test it, and the range remains fixed with the upper limit as the number of minutes **at the time of starting the server** ,i.e., when the model gets created. I want this range to be determined by the view, i.e., when the form is loaded on the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, this code does not belong in the model, but in the form.

Secondly, if you need things to be dynamic, they must go in the `__init__` method, not at class level. So:

```
class MemberForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = [..., 'batch', ...]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MemberForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        d = datetime.datetime.now().year
        ch = [(X,X) for X in range(2005, d)]
        self.fields['batch'].choices = ch
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the quick reply. Just one thing though, what did you mean by 'this code does not belong in the model, but in the form' ? Are you referring to the first two lines and thus implying that such logic should not be a part of the model? (Because I need to define my model with the help of the rest of the 'code', no?)

Comment: Yes, I mean the dynamic choices stuff. Obviously the fields definitions are part of the model, but you should remove the choices from there completely.

Comment: Hi Daniel, the statement `self.fields['batch'].choices = ch` doesn't work because IntegerField of forms does not have a choices attribute (that of models class does). I changed it to `self.fields['batch'].widget = forms.Select(choices=ch)` and it worked. Please make this change in your answer and I will mark it as correct.

Thanks for your help (y)